# Safari- show() and css('display','block') doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

I have to display a spinner.
The spinner has a class with the following style:

```
.spinner-ctn{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
}
```

For display the spinner I try to use:
a

```
function showSpinnerSignUp(){
    $('.spinner-ctn').css('display','block')
}
```

b

```
function showSpinnerSignUp(){
        $('.spinner-ctn').show()
    }
```

for some reason both of them doesn't work in safari

Comment: they look fine. which safari version? which jquery version? no console errors?

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle demo

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fav5o741/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fav5o741/2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fav5o741/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `#` to `<a href='#'` and put a space between  event. I try with safari work fine.

```js
$(document).on('click','.skip-step',function(e){
    $('.spinner-ctn').css('display','block')
})
```

```css
.spinner-ctn{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" event="next" id="skipBotton" class="skip-step pull-right">link</a>
<div class="spinner-ctn"><a class="spinner">test</a></div>
```

**UPDATE**

ok try, add class with `display: block !important` and toggle this.

```js
$(document).on('click','.skip-step',function(e){
    $('.spinner-ctn').toggleClass("spinner_block")
})
```

```css
.spinner-ctn{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
}
.spinner_block{
  display:block !important;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" event="next" id="skipBotton" class="skip-step pull-right">link</a>
<div class="spinner-ctn"><a class="spinner">test</a></div>
```

Comment: Actually it still doesn't work. I think the problem connect the fat that I use web flow of grails. In my app I don't use a, I use the following:                 <g:link event="next" id="skipBotton" class="skip-step pull-right"/></g:link>

Comment: FrankI use a webflow... when I click the g:lone with event=next it redirect me to another pade

Comment: @ P. Frank- unfortunately is still doesn't work. When I debug I can see that it stop in the toggle....but nothing happens

Comment: have you a link of your exemple page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93052/discussion-between-sarit-rotshild-and-p-frank).